# How do I check if my Discord.Net bot is already connected to a Voice Channel

Tags: c#, asynchronous, audio, console, discord.net

My bot can join and leave a voice channel without issue but how would I validate if it's already connected to a voice chat?

Code from my audio service .cs file

```
public async Task<IAudioClient> ConnecttoVC(SocketCommandContext ctx)
        {
            SocketGuildUser user = ctx.User as SocketGuildUser;
            IVoiceChannel chnl = user.VoiceChannel;
            if(chnl == null)
            {
                await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Not connected!");
                return null;
            }
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Joining Voice!");
            return await chnl.ConnectAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Check the `VoiceChannel` property of the `SocketGuild` `CurrentUser`. If it's null, the bot is not connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was using the `VoiceChannel` property of `.CurrentUser` to check if the bot is connected or not and I was having issues with the bot joining and leaving simultaneously or not joining at all. So I decided to just add a bool variable to my class and it works for me.

```
private bool voiceCheck;
        public AudioService() { voiceCheck = false; }

public async Task<IAudioClient> ConnecttoVC(SocketCommandContext ctx)
        {
            SocketGuildUser user = ctx.User as SocketGuildUser;
            IVoiceChannel chnl = user.VoiceChannel;
            if(chnl == null)
            {
                await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Not connected!");
                return null;
            }
            if(voiceCheck == true)
            {
                await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Already connected!");
                return null;
            }
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Joining Voice!");
            voiceCheck = true;
            return await chnl.ConnectAsync();
        }
```

Between my `ConnecttoVC` and `Leave`(omitted) methods, voiceCheck would switch between true and false while checking for each respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you had problems with the bot joining and leaving using the `VoiceChannel` property of the `CurrentUser`, but I needed my bot to know if it's in the same channel as the user who executed the command. So I went with that method and so far haven't had any problems when testing. I thought I'd share my code here for anyone else who is trying to work out how to do this. I've commented the code so it should hopefully be easy to understand.

```
public async Task<IAudioClient> ConnectAudio(SocketCommandContext context)
{
    SocketGuildUser user = context.User as SocketGuildUser; // Get the user who executed the command
    IVoiceChannel channel = user.VoiceChannel;

    bool shouldConnect = false;

    if (channel == null) // Check if the user is in a channel
    {
        await context.Message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Please join a voice channel first.");
    } else
    {
        var clientUser = await context.Channel.GetUserAsync(context.Client.CurrentUser.Id); // Find the client's current user (I.e. this bot) in the channel the command was executed in
        if (clientUser != null)
        {
            if (clientUser is IGuildUser bot) // Cast the client user so we can access the VoiceChannel property
            {
                if (bot.VoiceChannel == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bot is not in any channels");
                    shouldConnect = true;
                }
                else if (bot.VoiceChannel.Id == channel.Id)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Bot is already in requested channel: {bot.VoiceChannel.Name}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Bot is in channel: {bot.VoiceChannel.Name}");
                    shouldConnect = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unable to find bot in server: {context.Guild.Name}");
        }
    }

    return (shouldConnect ? await channel.ConnectAsync() : null); // Return the IAudioClient or null if there was no need to connect
}
```